# Tomcat Server unresponsive "http-nio-80-Acceptor-0"

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, garbage-collection

I've a spring boot(1.5.8.RELEASE) app running with 5GB RAM. When I hit the API with some request returning huge data it throws

```
> Apr 30, 2020 2:01:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause
```

The above exception is expected as the data size is huge and application is running out of memory. But if I hit API with the same request returning huge data my application throws the following exception and app becomes unresponsive and I need to restart it every time. But if I again hit the API with request returning less amount of data it works perfectly fine.

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-80-Acceptor-0"
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Apr 30, 2020 2:09:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Why is it throwing different exceptions for the same request? I analyzed memory using VisualVm memory was immediately getting clear after processing of requests and I've made sure there is no memory leak. Does this has something to do with `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource()` that I'm using?

Comment: _huge data_ will require huge heap. Period. If you can return that in portions, paginations, etc - do that, otherwise there is no magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error :  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

This error occurs when the JVM spent too much time performing Garbage Collection and was only able to reclaim very little heap space.

> According to Java docs, by default, the JVM is configured to throw
>   this error if the Java process spends more than 98% of its time doing
>   GC and when only less than 2% of the heap is recovered in each run. In
>   other words, this means that our application has exhausted nearly all
>   the available memory and the Garbage Collector has spent too much time
>   trying to clean it and failed repeatedly

#### Solution:

- Increase the heap size, for example -Xmx1g.
- the limit check can be disabled by adding the option
  -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line

You can set jvm env config at tomcat/bin/setenv.sh file like this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m  -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"
```

Comment: But why does it throw different exception for the same request?

Comment: both request give `GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: The second one gives exception in thread http-nio-80-Acceptor-0. Hence I thought it has something to do with tomcat

Comment: its jvm env config issue.... you can set this config at `tomcat/bin/setenv.sh`... your root cause is `GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: when u got out of heap space then tomcat give this error `http-nio-80-Acceptor-0`

Comment: Will try increasing heap space. Can you mention this in your answer too?

Comment: if there is no setenv.sh file in your tomcat. then u need to create it

Comment: Did you seriously suggest to enable `CMS` collector? It is deprecated and dead, and this will not help, either way

Comment: @Eugene thanks for this info... i did not know about this... i will update this answer... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when **the GC overhead is so great that the application spends almost all of the time on GC (98%) housekeeping activities**. Thereby the normal functioning of the application is thwarted and it becomes unresponsive. Rather than continuing with this the JVM spews out this error warning about this issue to be taken into account.

*Generally happens when:*

1. Heap size was limited for the objects created as in the normal processing of the application
2. There is a memory leak (it seems that there is none as per VisualVM)

I have seen GC spending cycles and almost all of the CPU when the cumulative size of objects and other data exceeded about 80% of the heap memory. This led to a GC and it could not reclaim much leading to another GC and so on.

In short, if you are sure there is no memory leak, the first thing you should try is:

1. Increase the size of the heap.

And also try to figure out the objects that are being created in the running of the use case by the application. Can you reduce that number? One use case, I remember, was reading a JSON file. Instead of reading the file and creating millions of JSON objects in heap, one could stream the file (as in Input Streams) and read it, create the object, operate upon it (and discard after computation) and move to the next one.

You could specify another GC algorithm (as specified elsewhere) but that would not solve the issue in this case. The issue seems to be unresponsive application and OOM and not merely of a higher latency of the application responses.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I can try increasing heap size but shouldn't it throw same exception all the time?

Comment: If the problem is that the heap is too limited for the objects etc. that your application creates increasing the heap would solve the issue. On the other hand if there is a memory leak or some other issues then the heap limit would be hit again.

Comment: I suggest you try to increase the heap and check if that resolves the issue. That is step 1.